# Impact mapping on a new project

Tags: scrum, agile, user-stories

I have read about a new technique for Agile Development named "Impact Mapping", developed by Gojko Adzic:
The main idea behind it is building a map of the business goals behind the project (the why), acters that are able to deliver the goal (the who), the change in behavior that will help reach the goal (the how) and finally the deliverables (the what), before starting with the first agile story. It helps keeping everyone concentrated on what matters the most which is delivering value.
My questions :

1. Any ideas about how to build an MVP using this method
2. Will i have an MVP for every Goal?

Comment: Impact analysis and software engineering paradigms need not be orthogonal, but neither are they intrinsically related. You might want to think about how your choice of an MVC  architecture maps onto your chosen decision-making methodology, but in the end this still seems like the tail wagging the dog.

Comment: What i meant is the MVP (Minimum Viable Product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean MVP (hope that's a correct assumption).

[This article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-build-an-mvp-in-the-right-way-in-2018-f538df0f2bba) sums up what a good MVP should deliver well:

- Serve at least one specific audience
- Address at least one key problem
- Have a well-designed User Interface (<- this feels open to interpretation)
- Be easy to build and launch quickly

From that perspective, I could see building an impact map and then asking questions like:

- Which of these actors is the most important audience?
- Which of these problems is central to the product?
- Which of these impacts would be most valuable to learn about?

It is important to remember that the goal of an MVP is to learn more about the needs of the user. So when you look at the impact map, it is important to consider what you want to learn.